# VS Code on Mac goes CPU bound at Startup

Tags: cpu, visual-studio-code

I'm having a weird problem, I've tried 3 different versions of VS Code 1.2, 1.3 1.4 and all are experiencing the same problem. One of the VSCode background processes hogs the CPU making the IDE very slow. I have not loaded any project, just starting VSCode causes the problem

[image]

Currenty I'm running Windows 10 under OSX 10.11 using VM Fusion, but if I run VSCode natively under OSX I experience the same problem. Running VSCode natively on a different laptop works fine.

Comment: This question maybe better suited for http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

This problem seems to be fixed with version 1.7

Comment: I have the exact same problem in 1.8.1. There is still an [open issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/17097) and recent comments seem to indicate that this is an Electron problem. Apparently, this only happens on a single CPU computer.